# POCO - PropertyFileConfiguration save method always writes using ":" as delimiter

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

We are currently using POCO Library in our project. I am using `setstring` to set key and value map. If I try to save, I expect that the file should be saved with `key= value` format. But POCO Saves it as `key: value` format.

Is there any way to Save the file with `key=value` format?

Example:

```
Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Util::PropertyFileConfiguration> pConf;
pConf = new poco::Util::PropertyFileConfiguration(file1);
pConf->setString("key1","value1");
pConf->save(file1);
```

Output of file1:

```
key1: value1
```

But I am expecting the output should be:

```
key1= value1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that I am aware of. The class `PropertyFileConfiguration` is able to load both formats `<key> = <pair>` and `<key> : <pair>` but it can only save using the `<key> : <pair>` format.

From the [documentation](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Util.PropertyFileConfiguration.html#26935):

> **save**
>
> void save(
>       std::ostream & ostr
>   ) const;
>
> Writes the configuration data to the given stream.
>
> The data is written as a sequence of statements in the form **<key>: <value>** separated by a newline character.

If there is no other option really, you could add your own `saveUsingEqual()` function to `PropertyFileConfiguration`. The code for the original `save()` is pretty straightforward:

```
void PropertyFileConfiguration::save(std::ostream& ostr) const
{
    MapConfiguration::iterator it = begin();
    MapConfiguration::iterator ed = end();
    while (it != ed)
    {
        ostr << it->first << ": " << it->second << "\n";
        ++it;
    }
}
```

So you would just need to replace the `": "` with `"= "`.